# Android app alternate installation source?

Tags: trello, android

I want to use the new Trello Android app on a tablet (Velocity Cruz T301) that does not have access to the Google Play Store.  It only has access to the Amazon store and the manufacturer's own app store.

Is there an alternate way of downloading and installing the app, other than through the Google Play Store?

Comment: Have the Trello folks made the `.apk` available for download? If not, they should. And, if they get around to adding it to some alternative markets, [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/what-are-the-alternative-android-app-markets) should be helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about installing a native Android app. It belongs at [android.se].

Answer (score 3):

According to [this comment](http://blog.trello.com/trello-android-app-available-for-download/#li-comment-1681), it should be appearing in the Amazon store "after a bit of testing". If you are keen, maybe you could try volunteering to be a tester :-)